# Save as a new version if file already exists

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that looks for the existing sequence number in the folder and save as new sequence number if it doesn't exist. For example, I have a filename `YYYYMMDD - 1` already in the folder. Now the macro should look for the `1` and add `+1` to that and save as `YYYYMMDD - 2` and so on. The existing macro that I have is as below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim FileName1 As String
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AD9:AM10")) = 0 Or _
        WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AD10:AM11")) = 0 Or _
        WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("AD12:AM12")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please select the Requirements of the sheet"
        End ' stops the macro from running
    Else
        Path = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/"
        FileName1 = Range("$B$2").Text
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & ".xlsm", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Range("$G$6").Value = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
End Sub
```

I have a macro button that generates a new date every time it is clicked so creating a date is not the issue but it would be good if the same macro also looks for the date and generates new date for the following day.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to look for the `1` and add `+1` and save as `YYYYMMDD - 2`? If you have tried then where are you stuck? If not, then why not?

Comment: **Hint:** Use a loop to create a filename `YYYYMMDD - n` and then check if the file exists using `DIR`. If it exists then increment `n` and recheck

Comment: Hi Siddharth, what I have tried is basically add "Range("$G8").Value = Range("$G8").Value + 1" to the command button folder which creates + 1 number everytime you click the button. But in this case, I need the VBA to search for the number(in this case, 1 or 2 or 3) and if they already exist, then genereate "4" or else "1" and save as .xlsm file in the path.

Comment: Like I mentioned, you need to use a loop to check if `Path & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & " - " & n & ".xlsm"` exists using DIR. See my previous comment

Comment: Yes, I understand logically that I need to create a loop but what and where the particular syntax will be is a mystery to me. It would be very nice of you if you can help me out with this complexity as I am no coder. Thanks!

Comment: I can give you the code but that will not help you learn. You can look at these few things and then try it. If you get stuck then post the code that you tried and we can take it from there? [FOR Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement), [DIR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dir-function) and [String Concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/concatenation-operator)

Comment: If you try and help yourself, trust me I will stay till the end till this is solved but if you want the code in the platter then I guess I will let someone else take over :)

Comment: Thanks!. I will bang my head a little bit more and then paste the code here after some time.